# to remove first and last element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to remove first and last element in an array?

For example:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

Expected output array:

```
["Orange", "Apple"]
```

Comment: this looks like a 'soft ball' for  creating links to w3schools, you've even used the same array elements. ;-)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

```
fruits.shift();  // Removes the first element from an array and returns only that element.
fruits.pop();    // Removes the last element from an array and returns only that element.
```

[See all methods for an Array.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fprototype#Methods)

Comment: It's easier with jQuery UI `myArray.effect( "transfer", { item: 'first&&last', to: bin});`

Comment: Dear downvoters, you might want your downvotes to be helpful, so please add a comment explaining what's wrong with the answer..

Comment: This will return only that removed (first or last) element's value, not remaining array

Comment: @RC. Just want to inform User about actual work of function. I am questioning on your answer.

Comment: Like User use this function as same as you write it definatly works proper as remove element, BUT if user write `return fruits.shift()` it will return ONLY that first element and then remove from array.

Answer (score 115):

Creates a 1 level deep copy.

```
fruits.slice(1, -1)
```

Let go of the original array.

Thanks to @Tim for pointing out the spelling errata.

Comment: I think you mean `slice()` rather than `splice()`.

Comment: Slicing fruit is way better than popping or shifting fruit.

Comment: with increment popularity of redux, functional javscript and immutable things this answer is way better

Comment: or `arr.slice(n, -n)` to remove any number from each end

Answer (score 26):

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var newFruits = fruits.slice(1, -1);
console.log(newFruits); //  ["Orange", "Apple"];
```

Here, -1 denotes the last element in an array and 1 denotes the second element.

Comment: Or just `fruits = fruits.slice(1,-1);` if you don't have to create a new variable.

Answer (score 9):

I use splice method.

```
fruits.splice(0, 1); // Removes first array element

var lastElementIndex = fruits.length-1; // Gets last element index

fruits.splice(lastElementIndex, 1); // Removes last array element
```

To remove last element also you can do it this way:

```
fruits.splice(-1, 1);
```

See [Remove last item from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544452/remove-last-item-from-array) to see more comments about it.

Comment: Might as well use `shift()` or `pop()` if you're mutating the array.

Answer (score 5):

`push()` adds a new element to the end of an array.
`pop()` removes an element from the end of an array.

`unshift()` adds a new element to the beginning of an array.
`shift()` removes an element from the beginning of an array.

To remove first element from an array `arr` , use `arr.shift()`
To remove last element from an array `arr` , use `arr.pop()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Code:

```js
const fruits = ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango'],
      result = fruits.reduce((a, c, i, array) => 0 === i || array.length - 1 === i ? a : [...a, c], []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Cool to see reduce to remove the first and last item!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with lodash [`_.tail`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#tail) and [`_.dropRight`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#dropRight):

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
console.log(_.dropRight(_.tail(fruits)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

For avoiding **Mutation** and changing the source array, a ***ReactJS*** developer cannot use `pop`, `shift` function, because both will change the source array and this kind of changes are root of very deep bugs.

The best way is using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) JavaScript built-in function. This function will create a slice of the source array and return for you a new array, also it accept negative index numbers, it means the first negative number is the latest item in array. so:

```js
fruits.slice(a, b)
```

- The first argument means start from index `a` and the index `a - 1` isn't wanted.
- The second argument means slice end in index `b - 1` and the index `b` isn't wanted.

So by the above explanation if we put `a = 1` it means we don't want first element and if we put `b = latest` it means slicing will end in index `b - 1` and we don't what index `b`.

**✨**: What was the index of latest element in the `slice` function? correct `-1`.

✅ So the final answer is:

```js
fruits.slice(1, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove element from array is easy just do the following

```
let array_splited = [].split('/');
array_splited.pop()
array_splited.join('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have array named list. The **Splice()** function can be used for both adding and removing item in that array in specific index i.e that can be in the beginning or in the end or at any index. On the contrary there are another function name **shift()** and **pop()** which is capable of removing only the first and last item in the array.

> This is the Shift Function which is only capable of removing the first element of the array

```
var item = [ 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34 ]; // say you have this number series 
item.shift(); // [ 1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34 ];
```

> The Pop Function removes item from an array at its last index

```
item.pop(); // [ 1,2,3,5,8,13,21 ];
```

> Now comes the splice function by which you can remove item at any index

```
item.slice(0,1); // [ 2,3,5,8,13,21 ] removes the first object
item.slice(item.length-1,1); // [ 2,3,5,8,13 ] removes the last object
```

> The slice function accepts two parameters (**Index to start with**, **number of steps to go**);

Answer (score 0):

> I over through all the notable answers. I am pointing you
> out a different answer. It works for me. I hope it will help you

```
fruits.slice(1,fruits.length-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Using `slice(1, -1)`:

###### Example

```js
> l = [5, 3, 10, 6]
[ 5, 3, 10, 6 ]
> l.slice(1, -1)
[ 3, 10 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use  the `delete` operator, then filter the array:

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// Delete the first item
delete myArray[0];
// Delete the last item
delete myArray[myArray.length - 1];

console.log(myArray) // Output: [null, 2, 3, null]

const finalResult = myArray.filter(x => x);

console.log(finalResult) // Output [2, 3]
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score -1):

You used
Fruits.shift() method to first element remove .
Fruits.pop() method used for last element remove one by one if you used button click.
 Fruits.slice( start position, delete element)You also used slice method for remove element in middle  start.

Comment: read this and format your answer correctly https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score -1):

```
var resident_array =  ["RC_FRONT", "RC_BACK", "RC_BACK"];
var remove_item = "RC_FRONT";
resident_array = $.grep(resident_array, function(value) {
            return value != remove_item;
    });
resident_array = ["RC_BACK", "RC_BACK"];
```

Comment: Remove first element from array.

Answer (score -1):

To remove the first and last element of an array is by using the built-in method of an array i.e `shift()` and `pop()` the `fruits.shift()` get the first element of the array as "Banana"  while `fruits.pop()` get the last element of the array as "Mango". so the remaining element of the array will be `["Orange", "Apple"]`

Comment: the answer you gave is already existing in this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4644159/4464653) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50600222/4464653). If you feel like they need more explaination, please leave a comment under the answer that you're not satisfied with.

Comment: Formatting your code will help (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)! Additionally, this answer seems identical to others (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43327999/608312).

Comment: Noted @JakeSteam