# Remove last item from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have the following array.

```
var arr = [1,0,2];
```

I would like to remove the last element i.e. 2.

I used `arr.slice(-1);` but it doesn't remove the value.

Comment: use arr[.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Comment: `arr.slice(0,-1)` was the best solution for me

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous since "remove last element" might mean remove the element from the array and keep the array (with one element less). But it might also mean to remove the element and keep the element. First case: `splice()`, second case: `pop()`.

Comment: `arr.length = arr.length - 1`

Comment: Code formatting for [@Anja Ishmukhametova's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2388994/anja-ishmukhametova) 2015 comment: "`arr.splice(-1,1)` will return to you the array `[1,0]`; `arr.slice(-1,1)` will return to you `[2]`"

Answer (score 749, accepted):

Use [splice(startPosition, deleteCount)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
array.splice(-1)
```

```js
var array = ['abc','def','ghi','123'];
var removed = array.splice(-1);  //last item
console.log( 'array:', array );
console.log( 'removed:', removed );
```

Comment: Anton what if I want to get the last value only for eg 2 and remove 1,0.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra You want to remove 1 and 0? So the array ==[2] ?

Comment: Then you can do this arr.splice(0,2) @PrithvirajMitra

Comment: So 0 is the starting position and 2 is first two values? In that case can I do like this arr.splice(0,(arr.length - 1)) ?

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra Yeah that should work completly fine, and yea 0 is starting position and 2 is how many you want to remove

Comment: Doesn't work for one-element arrays: `[1].splice(-1, 1)` => `[1]`

Comment: Pop on its own will only return the value of the last element. If I understand correctly, @PrithvirajMitra wants two things: 1) To remove the last element from the original array, and 2) return that element as a single element array - ie: `[0,1,2] -> [2]`, leaving behind `[0,1]`. If that's the case, then `[arr.pop()]` will do the trick.

Comment: Note that `array.pop()` will change modify `array`, while `slice(0, -1)` will not. Pop is of course faster but may not be always suitable for all needs.

Comment: Using splice is a recipe for misunderstanding, Use pop like suggested below

Comment: be careful using `new var = arr.splice(-1,1)` this returns the spliced value and not the new array. (just happened to me)
First splice and then set the `new var`

Comment: wtf?? it returns empty array

Comment: this solution is just great if you want to "drop all but the last item". But it should not be the correct answer in this thread

Comment: wrong: pop() returns the removed element, splice() returns the spliced selection - better use arr.filter((e, i) => i !== arr.length - 1) or do as @vinni said

Comment: If you want to remove n element from array: arr.splice(-n, n);

Comment: @BenHull `[1].splice(-1, 1)` > returns removed item, thats why you see `[1]` at the end. However, if you try this`var a = [1]; a.splice(-1, 1); ` you will see `a : []`

Comment: It's important to know about side effects. If you *want* to modify the original, then use `pop()`, if you don't, use `splice()`.

`splice()` is like creating a defensive copy, once the copy is made you can do whatever you want to it and not worry about the original. In my case, I `return array.filter(...).splice(...)`

`pop()` is useful when you have a to-do list for example, and you want to mutate it every time. If I used pop for my case, it would have caused bugs.

If the array only has a few items in it performance is negligible. Mine had 13 items. Memory and cpu are not at stake.

Comment: Another hint: If you use `.splice(-n,n)`, you can ommit the `,n` as `splice(-n)` deletes all elements from "the n-th from behind", which are `n`  elements including "the `-n`-th one" which is exactly the same. @grego are you mistaking `splice` for `slice`?

Answer (score 1007):

[Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) by JavaScript convention.

```js
let fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'tomato'];
let popped = fruit.pop();

console.log(popped); // "tomato"
console.log(fruit); // ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
```

Comment: Array.prototype.pop() appears to be the fastest http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-splice-vs-pop/3

Comment: When using pop(), be sure not to do jQuery('#foo').val(numbers.pop()), unless you only want to place the last item of the array into the field. pop() returns the element removed. As Stuart has done, first do numbers.pop(); and then do jQuery('#foo').val(numbers)...

Comment: it would be cool to have unpop() that returns rest of the array.

Comment: Any way to do this while keeping the array immutable?

Comment: @nayiaw Yep, ES6 spread syntax:

`let fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'tomato'];`
`let popped = [...fruit].pop();`

popped then equals `tomato` and fruit still equals `['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'tomato']`.

Comment: Made [@Viacheslav Dobromyslov's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1177597/viacheslav-dobromyslov) comment readable: "Does not fit case when you want to `string[][].map()` and remove last element from each `string[] subarray`. But it could be solved with `rows.forEarch(row => row.pop())`"

Answer (score 456):

You can do this using [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method like:

```
arr.slice(0, -1);    // returns [1,0]
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var arr = [1, 0, 2];
var newArr = arr.slice(0, -1);    // returns [1,0]

console.log(newArr);
$('#div1').text('[' + arr + ']');
$('#div2').text('[' + newArr + ']');
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Original Array    : </b>
<div id="div1"></div>
<br/>
<b>After slice(0, -1): </b>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

instead of doing :

```
arr.slice(-1);   // returns [2]
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var arr = [1, 0, 2];
var newArr = arr.slice(-1);    // returns [2]

console.log(newArr);
$('#div1').text('[' + arr + ']');
$('#div2').text('[' + newArr + ']');
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Original Array    : </b>
<div id="div1"></div>
<br/>
<b>After slice(-1): </b>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

### **Explanation:-**

Now the basic syntax of `Array.prototype.slice()` or in short `slice()` method is:

```
arr.slice([begin[, end]])
```

Here,

the `begin` parameter is zero-based index at which extraction from an array starts. So, lets say based on above example if we do something like

```
arr.slice(0)    // returns [1,0,2]
```

it would return all the array elements from start of sequence from position 0 and that is `[1,0,2]`. Similarly, if we do

```
arr.slice(1)    // returns [0,2]
```

it would return `[0,2]` since 0 is at position 1 here and everything after that. Now, in your case you have passed a negative index i.e., `-1` as the begin parameter, which indicates an offset from the end of the sequence. So, `slice(-1)` in your case extracts the last one array element in the sequence and that is `2` (*as we have already seen in the above demo*).

Now, let's talk about the `end` parameter in the `slice()` method syntax here. It is again a zero-based index at which extraction from an array ends. So, lets say we have a array like:-

```
var arr = [1, 0, 2, 5, 3, 9];
```

and we want to get just the `2,5,3` elements in the array. Now, position of `2` from start of the sequence is `2` and for last element `3` it is `4`. We will need to end the extraction here a position 5, as we need to get the element before that position. So, we will simply implement `slice()` method here like

```
arr.slice(2, 5)    // returns [2,5,3]
```

In your case, we have implemented `-1` as the end parameter, so our code is like

```
arr.slice(0, -1)   // returns [1,0]
```

As a negative index, `end` indicates an offset from the end of the sequence. So, `slice(0,-1)` extracts the first element through the second-to-last element in the sequence. So, we get the desired output. We can also do like

```
arr.slice(0, 2)    // returns [1,0]
```

we will get the same output. But, I have used `-1` here as its easier to implement even for a long array like

```
[0,2,3,1,2,9,3,6,3,9,1,0,2,9,0,1,1,2,3,4,7,9,1]
```

If you just want to remove the last element, you don't want to sit & calculate the position of last 9 here and the do like `arr.slice(0, 22)`. You can then simply implement the negative index logic here & do

```
arr.slice(0, -1) // same result as arr.slice(0, 22)
```

Comment: This works great, just make sure you notice that this is a call to .slice() and not to .s**p**lice().

Comment: It should be noted that this solution **does not remove** the last item from the array `arr` but rather returns a new array which excludes that last item. As Mozilla's docs say: "The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.".

Comment: The sample code of the question implicitly ask how to get a new array with the last value removed from the original array. So `arr.slice(0, -1)` is the best answer.

Comment: slice is better since it doesn't modify original array

Answer (score 186):

**learn by example:**

```
let array_1 = [1,2,3,4];
let array_2 = [1,2,3,4];
let array_3 = [1,2,3,4];
let array_4 = [1,2,3,4];

array_1.splice(-1,1)  // returned --> [4]      array_1 = [1,2,3]
array_2.slice(0,-1);  // returned --> [1,2,3]  array_2 = [1,2,3,4]
array_3.pop();        // returned --> 4        array_3 = [1,2,3]
array_4.shift();      // returned --> 1        array_4 = [2,3,4]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it illustrates what _most_ get wrong. > Returning the array you want **OR** mutating the array in the way you want.

Comment: if you use `.splice(-1,1)`, you can ommit the `,1` as `splice(-x)` deletes all elements from the `-x`-th, which is the `x`-th from behind. With `-1` for `-x` all elements from "the last one" is exactly the same as "the last one".

Comment: @Cadoiz using language's default like this is cool when you know this behaviour, yet many devs who will see your code may not have this knowledge and in my opinion it's more readable and more bugs-proof when is defined and not skipped though.

Answer (score 108):

You would need to do this since `slice` doesn't alter the original array.

```
arr = arr.slice(0, -1);
```

If you want to alter the original array you can use `splice`:

```
arr.splice(-1, 1);
```

or `pop`:

```
arr.pop();
```

Comment: if you use `.splice(-1,1)`, you can ommit the `,1` as `splice(-x)` deletes all elements from the `-x`-th, which is the `x`-th from behind. With `-1` for `-x` all elements from "the last one" is exactly the same as "the last one".

Answer (score 31):

I would consider `.pop()` to be the most 'correct' solution, however, sometimes it might not work since you need to use array without the last element right there...

In such a case you might want to use the following, it will return `[1,2,3]`

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(arr.splice(0,arr.length-1));
```

while `.pop()` would return `4`:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(arr.pop());
```

which might not be desirable...

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: Thanks dude, this is the exact example that I need to use. I appreciate that :)

Comment: This is the most correct answer. Its a shame others have ranked higher.

Comment: You can omit the `0` in `arr.splice(0,arr.length-1)`

Answer (score 20):

Just use the following for your use case:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.pop() //returns 4 as the value
arr // value 4 is removed from the **arr** array variable
```

Just a note. When you execute `pop()` function even though the line returns the popped item the original array is effected and the popped element is removed.

Answer (score 19):

There is a function for that, explanation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp):

```
arr.pop();
```

Answer (score 14):

You could simply use, `arr.pop()`

This removes the last entry of the array.

```
var arr = [1,0,2]; 
var popped = arr.pop();//Now arr = [1,0] & popped = 2
```

Answer (score 12):

`arr.slice(-1)` will return a *copy* of the last element of the array, but leaves the original array unmodified.

To remove the last `n` elements from an array, use `arr.splice(-n)` (note the "p" in "splice").  The return value will be a new array containing the removed elements.

Simpler yet, for `n == 1`, use `val = arr.pop()`

Answer (score 12):

It's worth noting that `slice` will both return a *new* array, whereas `.pop()` and `.splice()` will mutate the *existing* array.

If you like handling collections of data with a chained command style, you will really want to stick with `slice` for something like this.

For example:

```js
myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var newArrayOfThings = myArray
  .filter(x => x > 5)              // only bigly things
  .slice(0, -1)                       // get rid of the last item ! slice(-1) will give first element
  .map(x => `The number is: ${x}`);// map to a set of strings
```

It can require a lot more messing about, and variable management, to do the same kind of thing with "pop", since unlike `map`, `filter`, etc, you don't get a new array back.

It's the same kind of thing with `push`, which adds an item to the end of an array.  You might be better off with `concat` since that lets you keep the flow going.

```js
myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var newArrayOfThings = myArray
  .filter(x => x > 5)              // only bigly things
  .slice(-1)                       // get rid of the "10"
  .concat([100])                   // note with concat, you must pass an array
  .map(x => `The number is: ${x}`) // map to a set of strings
```

Answer (score 10):

```js
var arr = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ];

// using slice
arr = arr.slice(0, -1);
console.log('arr : ', arr);

// using splice
arr.splice(-1);
console.log('arr : ', arr);

// using pop
arr.pop();
console.log('arr : ', arr);

// using shift and reverse
arr.reverse().shift()
arr.reverse();
console.log('arr : ', arr);

// using spread Operator and reverse
const [, ...exceptLast] = arr.reverse();
arr = exceptLast.reverse();
console.log('arr : ', arr);

// removing last index
arr.length -= 1;
console.log('arr : ', arr);
```

Comment: Are there any side effects of just decrementing the `length`, such as memory leaks or the like. (Your last suggestion `arr.length -= 1;` as [in Joby Joseph's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544452/remove-last-item-from-array/38713275#comment129445728_19544452)) Otherwise, this is a neat solution. Another note: if you use `.splice(-1,1)` as in your second suggestion, you can ommit the `,1` as `splice(-x)` deletes all elements from the `-x`-th, which is the `x`-th from behind. With `-1` for `-x` all elements from "the last one" is exactly the same as "the last one".

Comment: `arr.length -= 1;` and `arr.length = arr.length - 1;` both have same meaning.

Comment: Yes of course, but that was not the question if there are any memory leaks or other side effects in doing so. Or put differently: Is there some GC that knows "this element is out of bounds and hence deleted"? `++arr.length` afterwards gives: `"arr : ", [0, 1, undefined]` which suggests it's fine.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it in two way using `splice()`:

1. `arr.splice(-1,1)`
2. `arr.splice(arr.length-1,1)`

`splice(position_to_start_deleting, how_many_data_to_delete)` takes two parameter.

`position_to_start_deleting` : The zero based index from where to start deleting. 
`how_many_data_to_delete` : From indicated index, how many consecutive data should be deleted.

You can also remove the last element using `pop()` as `pop()` removes the last element from some array.
Use `arr.pop()`

Answer (score 8):

Another approach is to filter based on index:

```
arr.filter((element, index) => index < arr.length - 1);
```

Note: `filter()` creates new array, doesn't change existing one.

Answer (score 6):

> This method is more helpful to delete and store the last element of an
>   array.

```
var sampleArray = [1,2,3,4];// Declaring the array
var lastElement = sampleArray.pop();//this command will remove the last element of `sampleArray` and stores in a variable called `lastElement` so that you can use it if required.
```

> Now the results are:

```
console.log(sampleArray); //This will give you [1,2,3]
console.log(lastElement); //this will give you 4
```

Comment: How is that different that this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19544509/5207515)?

Comment: Ya thats true but this one is more elaborated. Your answer is difficult to understand for a beginner.

Answer (score 5):

splice(index,howmany) - This solution sounds good. But This **howmany** will work only for the positive array index. To remove last two items or three items use the index itself.

For example, splice(-2) to remove last two items. splice(-3) for removing last three items.

Answer (score 5):

```
var arr = [1,0,2];
arr.length--;
```

removes the last element, but you might need to check if `arr.length > 0` first.

Comment: Are there any side effects of just decrementing the length? (such as memory leaks or the like)

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 
console.log(a.reverse().slice(1).reverse());
//Array(5) [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 4):

With Lodash you can use [dropRight](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#dropRight), if you don't care to know which elements were removed:

```
_.dropRight([1, 2, 3])
// => [1, 2]

_.dropRight([1, 2, 3], 2);
// => [1]
```

Answer (score 3):

**2019 ECMA5 Solution:**

```
const new_arr = arr.reduce((d, i, idx, l) => idx < l.length - 1 ? [...d, i] : d, [])
```

Non destructive, generic, one-liner and only requires a copy & paste at the end of your array.

Comment: 'Non destructive'  doesn't sound like what the original question wants: `I would like to remove the last element `. That needs a destructive/mutating operation on the original array.

Answer (score 2):

say you have `var arr = [1,0,2]`

`arr.splice(-1,1)` will return to you `array [1,0];` while  `arr.slice(-1,1)` will return to you `array [2];`

Answer (score 2):

Using the spread operator:

```js
const a = [1,2,3]
const [, ...rest] = a.reverse();
const withoutLast = rest.reverse();
console.log(withoutLast)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is good way to remove last item :

```
if (arr != null && arr != undefined && arr.length > 0) {
      arr.splice(arr.length - 1, 1);
}
```

Detail of splice as following:

*splice(startIndex, number of splice)*

Answer (score 1):

```
var stack = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

stack.reverse().shift();

stack.push(0);
```

Output will be: **Array[0,1,2,3,4,5]**.
This will allow you to keep the same amount of array elements as you push a new value in.

Comment: you need another reverse after your shift or after your push to get the right order again

Comment: Reverse reverses the original array. Has caught me out... lets say once or twice...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove n item from end of array in javascript, you can easily use:

```
arr.splice(-n, n);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a one-liner that doesn't require you to initialize multiple variables:

```
var arr = [1,0,2];

arr = arr.filter((_,i,a) => i !== (a.length-1));
```

Explanation:
We're using the [Array Filter Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which takes in 3 callbacks:

1. `element` (`_`): the current element during the iteration
2. `index` (`i`): the index of the element iteration
3. `array` (`a`): the array that is being used for the filter

So we just skip the element `if` it's the last element in the `array` that is being used.

The `_` is just a placeholder because we're not actually using it.

Comment: In this way, an array will be returned as opposed to the item that is being removed (using splice() or pop()

Answer (score 0):

Simply `arr.splice(-1)` will do.

Comment: No, to remove last item use `arr.slice(0, -1)`, and its not a modification, it should be saved like: `var newArray = arr.slice(0, -1)`

Comment: I agree @diti , it just a shorthand what I suggested.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Setup
var myArray = [["John", 23], ["cat", 2]];

// Only change code below this line
var removedFromMyArray;
removedFromMyArray = myArray.pop()
```

Comment: please add some comments apart from the raw code to make it a better answer.

Answer (score -9):

I got the best answer!

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array.length = array.length - 1

console.log(array)
> [1, 2, 3]
```

Honestly JS is a meme at this point.

PS: This affects the variable and any of its references, if you want to not affect any of the variable's references you can do:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var modifiedArray = Array.from(array)
modifiedArray .length = modifiedArray .length - 1

console.log(modifiedArray )
> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This is possibly an unsafe way of doing it and it might not work depending on the implementation of javascript, so don't use this.