# Remove the last item from an array (and not return item)

Tags: javascript, arrays

My current array: `abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];`

I understand `.pop()` remove and returns the last item of an array, thus: `abc.pop(); = 'd'`

However, I want to **remove the last item**, and return the array. So it would return:

`['a', 'b', 'c'];`

Is there a JavaScript function for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove last item from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544452/remove-last-item-from-array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pop()` function also removes last element from array, so this is what you want([Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rJc84/)):

```
var abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
abc.pop()
alert(abc); // a, b, c
```

Comment: Mind that code readability is as important as the amount of lines it takes or more.

Answer (score 4):

Do this

```
abc = abc.splice(0, abc.length-1)
```

Edit: It has been pointed out that this actually returns a new array(albeit with the same variable name).

If you want to return the same array, you'll have to make your own function

```
function popper(arr) {
   arr.pop();
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: Technically you're returning a new array, and not the original. This can cause problems in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

in an expression, using the comma operator.
( documentation:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator  // thx @Zero )

```
(abc.length--, abc)    

// expl :
  (abc.length--, abc).sort();
```

Or in a function, most handy being to set it on Array prototype :

```
 Array.prototype.removeLast = function () {
       this.length--;
       return this;
 }
```

called with

```
var abc = ['you', 'and', 'me'];
abc.removeLast();
```

which you can daisy chain :

```
abc.removeLast().sort();
```

Comment: Adedded plus, 'cause was the same approach I was going to suggest. However, a link to [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) documentation would be nice in the answer too, for the readers doesn't know how it works – the explanation in the code is not sufficient, IMVHO.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.popAndReturnArray = function( ){
   this.pop();
   return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you want is more generally the "filter" function.

It takes a function and returns everything that passes a test function, here's an example:

```
abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

abc.filter(function(member,index) { return index !== abc.length - 1; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Splice and pop will both return the removed element.  They will mutate the original array, but if you are looking for a function that returns the array without the removed element, use slice.  This way you can chain calls.

```js
let abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
abc = abc.slice(0, -1)
  .map(value => value += value);
console.log(abc);
// prints ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

Answer (score 0):

###### for change a default behavior of `pop()` method in javascript you have to change `prototype` of `pop` method

```js
Array.prototype.pop = function() {
    this.length = this.length - 1
    return this
}
```

```js
const abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
console.log(abc.pop());
```

###### also you can make another Array method like `removeLast` with your custom oputput:

```js
Array.prototype.removeLast = function() {
    this.pop()
    return this
}
```

> if you dont want to change the output globally it's better to log your data after pop()
>
> ```js
>    const abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
>    abc.pop()
>    console.log(abc);
> ```