# How to remove object/array from javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

**How to remove object/array from javascript variable?**

Comment: Remember to format the code in your question using the charachter ` or selecting the code and hitting the "format code" button. Anyway is not really important to post all the data... you could've just asked how to delete the last item in an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove last item from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544452/remove-last-item-from-array)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to remove the last element of an array.

```
bankBranchReponse.pop();
```

To remove an element at a specific index, for example the 3rd element:

```
var index = 2; // zero based so 2 is the 3rd element
bankBranchReponse.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: If I want to remove 3rd array then how will I do it?

Comment: If the array position is not fixed, then how you remove the array ? I mean not using index/position. May be by using for loop.

Answer (score 1):

As for W3CSchool http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp

You can use the **`.pop()`** method.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.pop();
```

The result of fruits will be:

```
Banana,Orange,Apple
```

**Remove another element**

To remove a certain element at an index inside the array you can use the method [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

So For example

```
var myFish = ['angel', 'clown', 'drum', 'surgeon', 'apple'];
// removes 1 element from index 3
removed = myFish.splice(3, 1);
```

And the result will be

```
myFish is ['angel', 'clown', 'drum', 'apple']
removed is ['surgeon']
```

Remember that array is zero-indexed so the 3rd element is the element number 2.

Comment: If I want to remove 3rd array then how will I do it?

Comment: Added to the answer how to remove any element from an array

Comment: :If the array position is not fixed, then how you remove the array ? I mean not using index/position. May be by using for loop.