# How to remove the last node of a node array?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a dom now which is like

```
span
span
p
p(to be removed)
p(to be removed)
```

and everytime a event was triggered, I d like to remove the last two p elements and append 2 more.

There is a node.removeChild method, but I tried, which turned out that the array of p is not the father element of p, but I do not know whether I did it the whole wrong way.

So, how could I remove the last two p nodes in the array of p, so I could clean the space and append two more?

Comment: `node.parentNode.removeChild(node)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove last item from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544452/remove-last-item-from-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, I finally made it myself.

The childNode.remove() method.

```
for (var index = here is the length you wanna reserve; index < the whole  array length; index++) {
    obj[index].remove();
}
```

Comment: Please don't put slang—like "ROFL" or "thx" or "plz"—in what you write. It's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```

The `parentNode` property will allow you to use `removeChild` in the way you intended to.

Answer (score -1):

declare a counter **i**, then check if it's between [number of p - 2 .. number of p]

```
var i = 0;
$("p").each(function(){
    if(i>=$("p").length-2)
         $(this).remove();
    i++;
});
```