# Remove from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove an element from an array using this instructions:

1. Use a loop to shift array values as follows. Starting with the index argument; for indexes less than length -  moving one index towards the end
                  set the array value at the current index to the array value at the following index

   ```
          Example: remove value at index 2 in List: a  b  c  d  e

                              0  1  2  3  4
                before loop:  a  b  c  d  e
          after loop pass 1:  a  b  d  d  e  (index 2 copies 'd' from index 3)
          after loop pass 2:  a  b  d  e  e  (index 3 copies 'e' from index 4)
          (loop ends)
   ```
2. Decrease array length by one; in JavaScript, this drops the last element from the array.

Why my code is not working?

```js
 this._data = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];


length() {
        return this._data.length;
    }
    
remove(index) {

            if (index === this.length()) {
                delete this._data[this.length()];
            }
            
            
            while (index < this.length()) {
                this._data[index] = this._data[index + 1];
                index++;
            }
            delete this._data[this.length() - 1];
            
    }
```

Comment: `.length` is an integer property, not a method

Comment: I suggest you use Google's Developer Tools to debug your code. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some general debugging tips.

Comment: *Why my code is not working?* Please elaborate. Error messages? Erroneous results? Both?

Comment: You are not supposed to use `delete`. Your second instruction tells you to just decrement the `.length`.

Comment: For starters open your browser console and look at the errors thrown

Answer (score 0):

Your code is awful, you couldn't use the property .length on something that doesn't have the attribute, you should initialize the object and call it after (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
arr.splice(2, 1); /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice */
/* ["a", "b", "d", "e"] */
```

or

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];        
function remove(arr, index){
    if(Array.isArray(arr) && Number.isInteger(index) && index >= 0 && index < arr.length){
        for(var i = index; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }
        arr.pop(); /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544452/remove-last-item-from-array */
    }
}   
remove(arr, 2);
```

Comment: Without using splice? Using a loop?

Comment: Maybe check if index is smaller than length, otherwise you always pop the array even if you don't remove anything.