# Remove last element of array in Redux with immutability-helper without knowing array's length

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, immutability, immutable.js

I am using `immutability-helper` (https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) to update state in Redux actions. I have an array and I'm adding an element like this:

`update(state, { modalAlerts: { $push : [payload] } })`

It works great. However, I don't know how to remove the **last** element of the array using Immutability Helper *without knowing the size of the array*. What is the equivalent of something like `update(state, { $pop: modalAlerts } })` (it doesn't exist) to remove the last element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking directly at the [source code for immutability helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper/blob/master/index.ts), it does not have what you are looking for. However you can [extend it per the docs](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper#adding-your-own-commands) to add that functionality.

This then becomes a question of how to remove the last element of an array, which is already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544452/remove-last-item-from-array) with a few options including using `pop`, but can be as simple as:

```
arr.splice(-1, 1);
```

Since immutability helper does have a [$splice command](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper#removing-an-element-from-an-array), that might enough.

Comment: I'll give it a try. However, I didn't get your last sentence regarding `splice` won't remove the last element, whereas you've said it might be enough in the previous sentence.

Comment: What I meant to say is that it will not remove the element if it is the only remaining element. And I'm pretty sure I was wrong about that because I just tested it. I removed that note from the answer. Thanks!