# How to remove an item from array Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am quite new to Typescript so apologises if it is a simple answer.

I'm looking to remove the end item from an array.

```
const arr = [];
```

array consist of 3 classes:

```
{class1,class2,class3}
```

if .push is to input, what is to remove?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove last item from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544452/remove-last-item-from-array)

Comment: "TypeError: arr[3].pop is not a function
Does seem to work, thanks though

Comment: the splice was correct, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Answer found here ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544452/remove-last-item-from-array)) by Darren z:

```
 arr.splice(-1)
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. If the linked post answers your question, you should close yours as a duplicate.