# How to hide the first and last object from the array in Excel export in kendo?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid in my ember app. i have to hide the first and last column in export to Excel and I have to modify the column width in the Excel sheet.

How to hide the object from the array?

Here is my code:

```
excelExport : function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var str = e.sender.columns;
     var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
     var tindex = str.map(function(d) { return d['title']; }).indexOf('Action');
     var dindex = str.map(function(d) { return d['field']; }).indexOf('documentKey');

     sheet.columns.removeObject(dindex);sheet.columns.removeObject(tindex);

     var excelSheetColumns = sheet.columns.filter(function(d){
     console.log(">>>>>>"+d);    
     //d.removeObject(tindex);
     //d.removeObject(dindex);            

     d.width = 50;
     return d;
});

var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
    sheets:e.workbook.sheets
});

kendo.saveAs({
    dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(),
    fileName:"export.xlsx"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var excelSheetColumns=sheet.columns.slice(2);
excelSheetColumns.forEach(function(col){col.width=50;});
var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
  sheets:excelSheetColumns
});
```

Comment: not working..how u will hide the first coloumn from theexcel sheet??

Comment: By using `excelSheetColumns`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: this is working but i need to remove 1st coloumn and last column from my excelsheet. All together i have 9 coloumn.

Comment: `var excelSheetColumns=sheet.columns.slice(1);` removes first element. `excelSheetColumns.pop();` removes last element. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644139/to-remove-first-and-last-element-in-array)

Comment: not working.. while downloading i am getting an empty worksheet